I can't install Anaconda, It say's that the folder I selected is not empty, and I checked all of my folders, what do I do, Im new to python
im trying to download Anaconda on windows but it keeps on telling me I have no space in any of my folders, I have 379GB free, any help would be greatly appreciated
I tried checking different files, or maybe checking if my laptop can't run it, my laptop is quite lowend

Can you give the output of "Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem"? While installing, make sure you install it on the desired drive (C, D, ...), maybe there is an option.

Do you have more than one hard drive?  If so, are you sure you're downloading it to the same drive that has the free space?

Also, "no space in any of my folders" does not seem to be the same error as "the folder is not empty".  What is the actual error message?

I'd suggest checking if you have space where you want to download it. On Windows, you can check the storage settings (Windows 11: Settings -> System -> Storage) to see if you have space.
Edit:
I also checked the system requirements for anaconda, and it needs at least 300 GB for storage and 32 GB of RAM. Double check the storage your system has and how it's distributed to see if you have enough for both.
